# Replace a Value in Header of Fixed width file

Tags: unix, scripting

I have below file which is Fixed width (Say 500 length)

```
1SomeTextintheHeader..
2.....................
2.....................
9.....................
```

The first row is Header in the example (Indicated by "1" in the first character) and starting from 12th character until 14th character the value in the header should be replaced with another value. So, in the example "the" should be replaced by another 3 character fixed value (lets say "myo").

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have some code for us to look at? We fix code. We don't write it for you.

Comment: Hey Marc, I am new to learning Sed. I have tried sed 's/The/myo/' Test File. But I am trying to find out how to only read block 1. I am researching as we speak.